# Unable to Detect textview field in Android Studio. Cannot resolve text view ID

Tags: java, android

I'm facing problems in my first attempt to use log files in a program. See this:

```
import android.os.Bundle; import
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//THIS HERE 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View; import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTextView; 
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setupUI();
 }
private void setupUI() {
     setContentView( R.layout.activity_main  );
     mTextView =  ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.textView );
 }

//Create a local variable for identifying the class where the log
statements  come from 

private final static String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 /** This method is called when the on screen button is passed.  *
 @param view  */

public void buttonPressed( View view ) {

    //An  'info'  log statement
     Log.i( LOG_TAG , "buttonPressed( View ) called" );

     //The string we wish to be displayed
     String stringValue = "Hello World!";
     //Change the text of the TextView on the screen
    mTextView.setText( stringValue );
   Log.v( LOG_TAG , "text changed to: " +stringValue ) ;
    //A debug log statement
   Log.d( LOG_TAG , "buttonPrssed( View ) finished" );

 }

 }
```

But the problem is that textView in the red cannot be resolved and TextView highlights as gray, why?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `activity_main.xml`? You can find it on **res** > **layout** > **activity_main**

Comment: Firstly, when ever you detect the "Id" cannot be resolved " Clean and Build" the project, Most of the cases have the build gradle issue. Secondly your question is not clear and not providing any layout file. Does the MainActivity has id textView??

Comment: Downvoted for unresponsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your R class doesn't have "textView".  Do you have something in a layout named with id="@+id/textView"?

Comment: Nope absolutely not

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem.  You haven't created anything that would generate that ID in the R class.  If you added a view in a layout with that same ID name, it'll generate a value in the R class for you.  But you haven't yet.